# How to get the actual workflow (event)

Tags: solidity, javascript, moralis

I've got several enums in solidity :

```
enum  WorkflowStatus {
        RegisteringVoters,
        ProposalsRegistrationStarted,
        ProposalsRegistrationEnded,
        VotingSessionStarted,
        VotingSessionEnded,
        VotesTallied
    }
```

In my front, I can click on a button which gonna call my function :

```
function startProposalsRegistering() external onlyOwner {
        require(workflowStatus == WorkflowStatus.RegisteringVoters, 'Registering proposals cant be started now');
        workflowStatus = WorkflowStatus.ProposalsRegistrationStarted;
        emit WorkflowStatusChange(WorkflowStatus.RegisteringVoters, WorkflowStatus.ProposalsRegistrationStarted);
    }
```

As you can see the workFlow change when I call this function. I would like to create an other button which gonna display the current workFlow, How can I do that with Moralis ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found how to do :)

```js
 const {
        runContractFunction: voting,
        data: enterTxResponse,
        isLoading,
        isFetching,
    } = useWeb3Contract({
        abi: [
            {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "workflowStatus",
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "internalType": "enum Voting.WorkflowStatus",
                        "name": "",
                        "type": "uint8"
                    }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function",
                "constant": true
            },
        ],
        contractAddress: 'contractAddress',
        functionName: "workflowStatus",
        params: {},
    })

<button
                onClick={async () =>
                    await voting({
                        onSuccess: (mess) => {
                            handleSuccess()
                            console.log(mess)
                        },
                        onError: (err) => {
                            console.log(err)
                        }
                    })
                }
            >
                Change status
            </button>
```

The console.log give me the right event :)

Thanks guys for your time !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the workflowStatus is being successfully updated in the contract state, you can listen for your event like this(from the docs https://docs.moralis.io/moralis-dapp/automatic-transaction-sync/smart-contract-events#watch-new-smart-contract-event:

// code example of creating a sync event from cloud code

```
let options = {
  chainId: "0x1",
  address: "0x5c69bee701ef814a2b6a3edd4b1652cb9cc5aa6f",
  topic: "PairCreated(address, address, address, uint256)",
  abi: {
    anonymous: false,
    inputs: [
      {
        indexed: true,
        internalType: "address",
        name: "token0",
        type: "address",
      },
      {
        indexed: true,
        internalType: "address",
        name: "token1",
        type: "address",
      },
      {
        indexed: false,
        internalType: "address",
        name: "pair",
        type: "address",
      },
      {
        indexed: false,
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "test",
        type: "uint256",
      },
    ],
    name: "PairCreated",
    type: "event",
  },
  limit: 500000,
  tableName: "UniPairCreated",
  sync_historical: false,
};

Moralis.Cloud.run("watchContractEvent", options, { useMasterKey: true });
```